# Error using Protractor 2.1.0 with CucumberJS

Tags: angularjs, cucumber, protractor, cucumberjs

I'm experiencing trouble upgrading to Protractor 2.1 from Protractor 2.0, and suspect it's an issue with the use of Protractor 2.1 and CucumberJS. When I edit the package.json to downgrade to Protractor 2.0.0, and reinstall the node packages, the issue is resolved. What's causing the error in Protractor 2.1.0? How can I rewrite my project to work with Protractor 2.1.0 and Cucumber JS?

My project files and their contents are listed below:

/path/to/myproject/**conf.js**

```
exports.config = {
  sauceUser: process.env.SAUCE_USERNAME,
  sauceKey: process.env.SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY,
  specs: [
    'features/*.feature'
  ],
  multiCapabilities: [
    {
      'browserName': 'chrome'
    }
  ],
  framework: 'cucumber',
  cucumberOpts: {
    require: 'features/stepDefinitions.js',
    format: 'summary'
  }
};
```

/path/to/myproject/**features/demo.feature**

```
Feature: Refund item

  Scenario: Jeff returns a faulty microwave
    Given Jeff has bought a microwave for $100
    And he has a receipt
    When he returns the microwave
    Then Jeff should be refunded $100
```

/path/to/myproject/**features/stepDefinitions.js**

```
module.exports = function() {
  this.Given(/^Jeff has bought a microwave for \$(\d+)$/, function (arg1, callback) {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    callback.pending();
  });

  this.Given(/^he has a receipt$/, function (callback) {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    callback.pending();
  });

  this.When(/^he returns the microwave$/, function (callback) {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    callback.pending();
  });

  this.Then(/^Jeff should be refunded \$(\d+)$/, function (arg1, callback) {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    callback.pending();
  });
};
```

/path/to/myproject/**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "strato-remake",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "conf.js",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cucumber": "0.4.9",
    "protractor": "2.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

When the node packages are installed, and Protractor is run:

```
$ npm install
$ $(npm bin)/protractor conf.js
```

The following error is printed to the terminal:

```
Using SauceLabs selenium server at http://ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[launcher] Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
  at formatter.handleBeforeFeatureEvent (/path/to/myproject/node_modules/protractor/lib/frameworks/cucumber.js:83:41)
  at /path/to/myproject/node_modules/protractor/lib/frameworks/cucumber.js:153:15
  at Function.promise (/path/to/myproject/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:650:9)
  at /path/to/myproject/node_modules/protractor/lib/frameworks/cucumber.js:147:14
  at _fulfilled (/path/to/myproject/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:797:54)
  at self.promiseDispatch.done (/path/to/myproject/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:826:30)
  at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/path/to/myproject/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:759:13)
  at /path/to/myproject/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:525:49
  at flush (/path/to/myproject/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
  at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)

[launcher] Process exited with error code 100
```

However, if I edit the package.json to downgrade to Protractor 2.0.0, and install the node packages again:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "cucumber": "0.4.9",
  "protractor": "2.0.0"
},
```

It then works when I run Protractor:

```
$ $(npm bin)/protractor conf.js

Using SauceLabs selenium server at http://ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
1 scenario (1 pending)
4 steps (1 pending, 3 skipped)
SauceLabs results available at http://saucelabs.com/jobs/8a85b85e7a1c5dd344e694e392ec90c3
[launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[launcher] chrome #1 passed
```

How do I rewrite this project for compatibility with Protractor 2.1.0 and Cucumber JS? Thank you!

Comment: Hi @AristarkhArtemiy, I've tried to implement what you did, but I keep getting:
[launcher] Error: TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/frameworks/cucumber.js:150:36
    at Function.promise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:650:9)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/frameworks/cucumber.js:147:14
    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:797:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the result of a bug in Protractor, which was fixed by [this pull request](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/issues/342#event-323484265). To use that particular commit, change your package.json to include:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "cucumber": "0.4.9",
  "protractor": "git+https://github.com/angular/protractor.git#0262268fa43b9eefac815d986740efa07bb15818"
},
```